# R: Is there a function like at_exit in the Ruby?

Tags: r

I want do something before exit the R program, just like in the Ruby we can do:

```
at_exit do
    print "before exit"
end
```

The on.exit in R, will do something before exit current function, but cannot work for whole program.

I've searched online, but cannot find useful info.

Comment: look at `.Last` and `reg.finalizer`

Comment: reg.finalizer seems work. I cannot find .Last or .last function in the R (version is 3.2.2). Thanks.

Comment: By the way, hrbrmstr, how can you find this function, I've searched a lot, but cannot find anything useful.

Comment: I also find how to use .Last in the R. Thanks.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html

Answer (score 3):

According to hrbrmstr's advice, I've tried .Last and reg.finalizer and they work. This is the summary:

Using .Last variable

```
.Last <- function() {
  cat("at last\n")
}
cat("ok\n")
```

The result will be:

```
[1] "ok"
at last
```

Using reg.finalizer function

```
reg.finalizer(environment(),
    function(e) cat("at last\n"),
    onexit=TRUE)
```

The result will be:

```
NULL
[1] "ok"
at last
```